# Passing multiple dataframes as arguments to a function

Tags: python, pandas

I have been scratching my head since morning on how to tackle this problem. I need to pass multiple columns from multiple dataframes to a function as arguments.

Example :
Df1

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 11 | 111,333 |
| 2 | 22 | 222 |
| 3 | 33 | nan |

Df2

| D | E |
| --- | --- |
| a | 111 |
| b | 333 |

Now, I want all the rows from Df2(col E) which are not present in the Df1 (Col C) along with DF1(A,B) concatenated.

The output I want is below:

| newcol | C |
| --- | --- |
| 2_22 | 222 |

I have written below code snippet to do the same but I'm stuck at how to apply it to the dataframes.

```
def get_wrong_ls(a,b,c,d):
    wrong_l_list = []
    wrong_l_dict = {}
    if c is not None:
        c_list = str(c).split(",")
        for ele in c_list:
            if ele not in d:
                wrong_l_dict[str(a)+"_"+str(b)] = c
            wrong_l_list.append(wrong_l_dict)
    return pd.DataFrame(wrong_l_list)
```

it returns correct output when the strings are passed. But I'm stuck at how to pass the dataframes directly. The below code behaves weirdly and also the "nan" in the col C doesn't get filtered out.

```
fd = get_wrong_ls(df1['A'],df1['B'],df1['C'],df2['E'])
```

Please help.

Comment: Could you update your question to show the desired output?

Comment: Would you please specify the inputs and desired outputs?

Comment: It looks like you're missing a lot of information and that the provided example doesn't reflect the real use case (why would you split a number on commas?)

Comment: I have edited the question to get the desired output. Please check. @Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3], 'B': [11, 22, 33], 'C': ['111,333', '222', np.nan]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'D': ['a', 'b'], 'E': [111, 333]})

def get_wrong_ls(df1, df2):
    df1.dropna(inplace=True)
    df1['C'] = df1['C'].str.split(',')
    df1 = df1.explode('C').astype(int)
    out = df1[~df1['C'].isin(df2['E'])].copy()
    out['newcol'] = out['A'].astype(str) + '_' + out['B'].astype(str)

    return out[['newcol','C']]

get_wrong_ls(df1,df2)
```

Output

```
   newcol   C
1   2_22    222
```

Comment: You are amazing!! I'm quite new to this and seem to get stuck at what looks like simple stuff but it's so hard to figure things out. Hopefully, It will get easier with time and practice.